# How to make a SVG gradually appear towards a certain angle with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, svg

Consider the SVG triangle below. I can make it appear from left to right like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#image').animate({
    width: 200
  }, 2000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<svg id="image" height="210" width="0">
  <polygon points="0,0 108,0 142,103" style="fill:black" />
</svg>
```

Now, is there any way I can make it gradually appear but with certain angle, starting on its hypotenuse and ending in the top right vertex?

Comment: Use CSS [transform](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/transform/).

Comment: Can you give me any guidelines on that? I only used CSS transform for really simple tasks. And will it work if I only want the element to appear in a certain order of jQuery animations? (for example, make triangle 1 appear, then triangle 2, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use SMIL animation. Because with this technique it is simple to chain animations directly in your SVG: [example](https://jsfiddle.net/x10eevd3/)

```
<svg id="image" height="300" width="300" viewBox="-50 -50 400 400">
  <polygon points="0,300 100,200 100,300" fill="yellow" stroke="black">
    <animateTransform
        attributeName="transform"
        id="first"
        begin="0s"
        dur="2s"
        type="rotate"
        from="0 100 300"
        to="90 100 300"
        fill="freeze"
        repeatCount="1" />    
  </polygon>
  <polygon points="200,300 300,200 300,300" fill="green" stroke="black">
    <animateTransform
        attributeName="transform"
        begin="first.end"
        dur="1s"
        type="rotate"
        from="0 200 300"
        to="-90 200 300"
        fill="freeze"
        repeatCount="1" />    
  </polygon>
</svg>
```

Look at the `begin="first.end"` attribute of the second animation. It is the way SMIL uses to say that this animation must start when the other (which I called `first`) ended.
Try things like this: `begin="first.end - 1s"`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it doesn't solve the problem but I wasn't unware of SMIL animations. Anyway, your example allows me to rotate the triangle, but what I need is to make it gradually appear. The position must be fixed all the times. Also, I should be able to trigger the effect through jQuery.